# How to send unhandled keypresses to a particular input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to do the following, seemingly simple thing.

> If a key is pressed that would have typed a character in a text input field, and that keypress is not already handled elsewhere (e.g. no input field had the focus), then **focus one particular input field and type the character there**.

This is to save users a mouse click in a browser game that requires quick responses, but it could equally well be used in, say, a chat application. If the user accidentally forgot to focus this (big and obvious) input field, then I want to handle this gracefully and not punish them.

Caveats:

- If any input field has focus, the event should go there and nowhere else.
- Keys that do not type characters (Enter, arrow keys, PgUp, PgDn, ...) should be left to do their default behaviour.

Using jQuery, I came up with something like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var input = $("#my-input-field");
  if (e.which >= ' ' && !input.is(":focus")) {
    input.focus();
    input.trigger(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

However, this does not work, for two reasons:

1. Events still bubble up to `document` even if a particular input field handles them. Possible solutions:

   - Hook up `keypress` event handlers to all input fields and call `stopPropagation` in each, but that sounds like a horrible hack waiting to go wrong.
   - Check in the above handler whether an input field currently has focus, and ignore it if so, but that sounds like I'd be missing some corner cases where something else is using the keypresses.
2. Calling `.trigger(e)` does not work. It does call my custom event handlers, but does not trigger the defaut `keypress` behaviour of actually inserting the character.

What is the cleanest way out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking about it, the events fire in this order: `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`.

You can use something like:

```
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input') {
        $('#my-default-input').focus();
    }
});
```

Then the keydown event will finish, it will later fire the keyup event (on the now-focused field) and should write the character into the field, and then fire the keypress event that other events (if any) tied to the field can use.

The contents of the if statement can be changed to filter out certain key presses, or to add other tags, like `<canvas>` to the "do-not-touch" list.

Also note that I haven't tested this, but it theoretically should work. :)

Comment: While this technique does work, it makes it hard to do the filtering because we now get keyCodes, not charCodes. However, based on this list: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes I managed to come up with something that works pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: Not even that's really necessary, just use [``String.fromCharCode()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode). :)

Comment: No, we're talking _key_codes here, not _char_codes. They're not the same thing.

Comment: They are almost always the same. Even the non-printable characters and some of the modifiers map to the correct ASCII value (which was adopted by UTF-8, which JS uses for strings). Only if you need to distinguish between keypad numbers and the number row of the keyboard, or if you need to pick up non-standard modifier keys like the Apple or Windows keys does it differ, and then you need [to check for every browser/OS combination](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html). Since you wanted to redirect "regular" keys ``/[A-Za-z0-9 .,\-+]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))`` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manually trigger a keypress for a user (potential security violation), all `trigger()` does in this case is fire any event listeners assigned to the keypress event. You can modify the value of the text box though using .val(). Just add the character to it.

You can test to see if the keypress was done in a textbox with `if($(e.target).is('input'))` in the document keypress listener. You can also add a check `'textarea'` if you wish.